# Using new lifecycle methods for fetching data by a changing id in React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-lifecycle

I have done it like this in `React` <= 16.2 :

```
componentDidMount () {
  fetchData(this.props.id)
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.id !== nextProps.id) {
    fetchData(nextProps.id)
  }
}

render() {
  if (this.props.isLoading) {
    return <Loader />
  } else {
    return <SuperComp this.props.data />
  }
}
```

The component was connected and `fetchData` was a `redux-thunk` action creator managing a simple state: `{ isLoading: ..., data }`. We can add error handling and cancellation on subsequent requests, but that is out of scope for now.

The basis of this is that the component requested it's own data every time the id prop changed, but only once for every change of the id prop.

I have no idea how it is properly done in `React` 16.4, the `getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static synchronous something returning the new state.

There is a [long comment](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/26) on github by bvaughn but it directly stores the data in state and initiates the refetch when the data is null. But if I store my data in `redux`, I cannot just null out my data in `getDerivedStateFromProps` (or can I?).

Can someone explain how can I do the same in "modern" `React`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to just use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) for that purposes (by the way examples from official documentation also suggest that).

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
    fetchData(this.props.id);
  }
}
```

What about [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) - they also warn about more simple alternatives:

> If you need to perform a side effect (for example, data fetching or an
>   animation) in response to a change in props, use componentDidUpdate
>   lifecycle instead.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I'm overcomplicating it.